PostGreSQL: cannot open relation
I am creating a procedure that receives as a parameter the license plate of a vehicle, inserts it in a temporary variable and returns this variable.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."GuardarPorPlca"(IN "Placa" character varying)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE tempInforme AS (
        radicado nchar(10),         
        fecha date,         
        codMarca nchar(20),         
        codLinea int,       
        numMotor varchar(20),       
        numChasis varchar(20),      
        codVehi nchar(20),      
        codColor int 
    );
    INSERT INTO tempInforme SELECT radicado, fecha, 
        codMarca, codLinea, numMotor, numChasis, codVehi, 
        codColor from Informe where placa LIKE $1;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$;

But when I go to test the procedure.
CALL public."GuardarPorPlca"(
    'XYZ-23A' 
)`

 I get the following error: 
`ERROR: cannot open relation “tempinforme”.
SQL state: 42809
Detail: This operation is not supported on compound types.
Context: PL/pgSQL function “SaveByPlca”(character varying) on line 12 in SQL statement.

I apologize if some variables do not correspond, it's just that I speak Spanish. Thank you.
I also attach an image of the report table in case it is needed:

The error message is pretty straight forward: Detail: This operation is not supported on compound types.. You cannot INSERT into a TYPE. You could need to CREATE TABLE to make this work. Though I am not sure why you want to do that in a procedure.

Also a PROCEDURE does not RETURN per plpgsql return.  You should add to your question what is you are trying to achieve.

What should this procedure do? Currently the entire logic is wrong, this can't work.
